# Convert Doxygen to XML comments

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, doxygen, xml-comments

We have a C# project which for historical reasons uses both Doxygen and Visual Studio style comments in the same code. 
Has anyone tried to systematically translate one standard to another, preferably to the common XML subset?

I guess it would not be too difficult to write a script to cover the most common features,
but I would not like to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, found these answers in 2022, maybe it can help someone:

- [Atomineer Pro](https://www.atomineerutils.com/) can convert between existing and your configured format
- [Doxygen to XML converter](https://github.com/JohnHardy/doxygentoxmlconverter) self-describing as quick and dirty Python tool